# Have no results SPARQL in Protege

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia, protege

I have a problem with my syntax I guess
I tried to fetch data from dbpedia by using SPARQL query in Protege 5.5

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX museum: <http://www.menthor.net/myontology#>
PREFIX dbp: <https://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX p: <http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/Museum/>


SELECT ?h
WHERE {
  ?h a p:collection .
  ?h rdfs:domain ?Museum .
 }
    LIMIT 5
```

I have an epmty result, there are no logs, no errors
What do I wrong?
How can I fix/rewrite it?

Comment: I don't know if you didn't understand last time, but this is not a `SERVICE` query, so it does only work on your local data. Is there any local data loaded in Protege that your SPARQL query would match?

Comment: and then ... what do you think `p:collection` results in as the full URI? Please open `http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/Museum` in your browser go to the list of properties of museum mappings. `collection` is a **property**, not a class, you have to use it as a property in SPARQL. With the correct namespace of course, like in your last question, either `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/collection` or `http://dbpedia.org/property/collection` - anyways, it doesn't work in Protege as it works on your local data as long as you didn't load DBpedia data

Comment: I need to use not local data, so what can I do? in this one I have empty white string as a result

    PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

PREFIX c: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/City/>


SELECT ?s ?Value

WHERE {

?s a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/City> .
?Value dbp:City ?s .

SERVICE <https://dbpedia.org/sparql>
{ 
}

}

Comment: Why not use dbpedia sparql endpoint? If you want to use it on protege then check out SPARQL SERVICE queries. It's not complicated.